# JavaFX applet problem

Tags: java, applet, javafx

I've create JavaFX applet.
It successfully starts under Windows XP/7 in different browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, IE)
Also it successfully starts under MacOS 10.6 (Mozilla, Safari)
But when I try to launch it under MacOS 10.5 (in Mozilla or in Safari) such exception is thrown:

```
liveconnect: JSObject::call: name=fxAppletStarted
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-8" java.lang.Error: Couldn't launch FX Stage FxInterface.Main
at com.sun.javafx.runtime.adapter.AppletStartupRoutineEx.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.swing.SwingToolkit$StartupRoutine.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:499)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:462)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:461)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:471)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:176)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:173)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:145)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:375)
at ProgramCore.JFXFacade.<init>(JFXFacade.java:28)
at FxInterface.Main$Main$Script.applyDefaults$(Main.fx:413)
at FxInterface.Main.javafx$run$(Main.fx:339)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
... 15 more
```

Does anybody know, what the trouble is?

Comment: Could be a difference in the Java version between OS X 10.6 and 10.5. I believe that 10.5 came with Java 1.5 and 10.6 is at Java 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From these messages, it looks like the MacOS 10.5 system is running an out of date JVM. Perhaps 1.5?

```
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110) Caused by:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaFX support is installed separate from the JVM, have you made sure it's installed?

Comment: There is such scheme of launching javafx applet:<script src="http://dl.javafx.com/1.3/dtfx.js"></script>
<script>
    javafx(
        {
              archive: "JFXapplet.jar",
              draggable: true,
              width: 650,
              height: 550,
              code: "FxInterface.Main",
              name: "JFXapplet"
        },
 {
       audioUrl: "test.wav", //jfxapplet parameters
       pictureUrl: "test.jpg"
 }
    );
</script>
As I know, such scheme of launching would load additional javafx modules if they needed.

Comment: Is there any solution - to make jfx applet launchable on macos 10.5 ?